# Why is the Back button of ios not visible always in ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am developing a app in ionic frame work. The back button of the ios build is not showing up sometimes. Is there any Specific reason for that?

Comment: In which cases is it not showing up? What version are you using?

Comment: It depends how you're using the state model. Sometimes it's automatically there, sometimes not, because that's the way the framework is built. If you do something that the designers expected the state model and the custom directives will have been designed to work together. It shouldn't be a problem - if you don't have a back button just put one in.